# Configure log4net logging in dll

Tags: c#, dll, log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm setting up a dll to be used as a third party dll for a different application. I want this dll to have it's own logging so the external application doesn't have to deal with setting up anything (I don't believe they use the same logging as we do). I've read that may not be the best solution but it's the task I've been given. We want to use log4net with this. I've looked at a few of the other questions on here and they mention that it is configurable via code, however, the main issue I'm having is that there is no clear cut entry point into our code to configure log4net. I'm curious if I should just abandon having the dll configure itself and have a method that is called by the secondary application that configures the dll's logging or if there is a better way to go about this. Any input would be much appreciated

Comment: You can configure log4net multiple ways including using a xml configuration file.  You either need to configure the logging settings through a startup method or set the configuration through the xml settings file.

Comment: Please clarify - do you want sample code that configures log4net for use by classes in your DLL, or do you want advice on where/how to call this sample code from your DLL?

Comment: @PaulF I don't need example code, I currently have it set up and working but I'm not a huge fan of the solution. Basically I have this:

` private void ConfigureLogging()
        {   
            XmlConfigurator.Configure(new System.IO.FileInfo(string.Format(@"{0}\{1}", System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, LogConfigurationFileName)));
        }`

This is called on the entry points to the dll to ensure that the logging knows which settings file to use. I was hoping to find a better solution than this.

Comment: Luckily it appears log4net does not recreate the file when this code is run so for now(we're still proving out the solution) this is working.

Comment: Its a bit of a pain but I think the config file is just going to be added to the msi of the other application. Its a little bit of overhead but apart from doing it all in code I don't see any other way. Its a bit of an odd scenario from a logging standpoint, since they do their logging differently than we do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can configure log4net programmatically. Perhaps add this code to the constructor of your DLL.

```
if (!log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().Configured)
{
    // my DLL is referenced by web service applications to log SOAP requests before
    // execution is passed to the web method itself, so I load the log4net.config
    // file that resides in the web application root folder
    var configFileDirectory = (new DirectoryInfo(TraceExtension.AssemblyDirectory)).Parent; // not the bin folder but up one level
    var configFile = new FileInfo(configFileDirectory.FullName + "\\log4net.config");

    if (!configFile.Exists)
    {
        throw new FileLoadException(String.Format("The configuration file {0} does not exist", configFile));
    }

    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(configFile);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This was what we ended up doing in the end just never updated the question.