# using log4net in .net c# library which is used by webservice app hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis, logging, log4net

we have .net webservice hosted in IIS.
The webservice using a library for socket communication to send and receive data from another tcp server.
The webservice using log4net (in web.config) for logging but there is no logging for the library.
Can we use a separate log4net for the library or how to use log4net for the library to log the details.

Comment: Do you have the code for the library? Is it using log4net already?

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem. If the WS is using log4net, then can't you just add a reference to the same version of the log4net assembly to your class library project, and use it for logging?  If you want to separate the logging output, you can use unique logger names in your class library, and configure log4net in web.config to output from these loggers to a different appender.

Comment: Thanks, we did the same and it resolved. But at present both ws and lib logs written in the same log file.Also followed the reference..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769414/configure-log4net-logging-in-dll  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed as per the instruction posted in 
[Configure log4net logging in dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769414/configure-log4net-logging-in-dll) 
But at present both ws and lib logs written in the same log file.