# C# how to log file inside a DLL?

Tags: c#, logging, dll, singleton, log4net

I'm developing a DLL and I want to log some data it generates.

I wanted to use "Log4Net", but I found the problem that in a DLL I don't have an "App.config" file where I can write the XML code, so I don't know how to implement this (I'm new in this matters).

I read about "Singleton" but I saw it's better to avoid it since it has it's issues (i.e hide some visibility of the code, problems with unit tests, ...).

So my question is: How and what is the best way to create a log file for the data generated by my DLL?

Comment: When you create a class lib or a dll, you don't have the App.config by default in your project but you can add it. If you are using VS, right click on the project, select Add -> New item and type config in the search box. A config file will be added to the project

Comment: You should not be logging in the DLL. Logging should be the job of the programmer *using* your dll. If every dll logs itself, that creates a anti-pattern of uncontrolable logging. | If it is a important thing, you should be throwing a Exception. If it is not important, you could provide a Event the user can register to. Or it is really just not that important that it needs logging. | When wrting a DLL, you generally have a seperate project working with the dll for debugging.

Comment: Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine. It is daunting thematic, even more if you have to consider throwing Exceptions yourself. But there are two articles that I link often and that I think can really help you: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Answer (score 4):

A DLL - a class library - should never be logging by itself. Even the ones that are there for output - like the one containing Console or even logger code - should never decide to write their own logfile. Logging work - all output work - that is not controllable or even fully controlled by the programmer using your DLL, is just going to be vexing behavior. And you should never write something with Vexing behavior.

**Logging is the job of the person using your code**, not of your code. If you are writing a Library or really anything else that usually has no output (like a Windows Service), it is customary to have a wrapper project for debugging and testing.

If it is important enough it warants an Exception. If it is not important enough for a Exception - it is propably not important enough at all. It is a daunting challenge to write good Exception handling, nevermind good Exception throwing code. But there are two articles on the mater that I link very often. And I really think would help you get you on the right paths:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

They really helped me get a handle on it. And thus far they helped countless others. And their ideas are not even tied to .NET only.

Comment: It depends on the project. when you are developing a plugin for another application that does not expose its types and is like a black box, your only chance to get an insight into your app behaviour is logging.

Answer (score 0):

The config file will be connected in running module.
It will be in `exe` file if it's a console application,
or in web.config in case of web application.

Answer (score 0):

To log the application flow in the DLL,
Just create a Class that create and access the log text file.

In that class, declare the object `LoggingClass loggingObject;` and then use this instance to access the log file.

In creating object for it, you can use,

```
public static LoggingClass createOrGetObject()
{
  return (loggingObject == null)? new LoggingClass() : loggingObject;
}
```

Now, just you can call this method to get the same instance that access the log file to write the log. 
In this example, Log4Net is not used but works fine for logging.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say who you expect to use your dll.

If it will be used by lots of other people and if the logging is useful to them, then may not want to be forced to use log4net or this may cause problems if they want to use a different version of log4net than you are using.

I have seen several dlls which use [Common.Logging](http://%20http://net-commons.github.io/common-logging/) to avoid this issue which allows the consumers to use whichever logging package they want.

Having said that, see [Configure log4net logging in dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769414/configure-log4net-logging-in-dll) for another possible solution.